# Cual es la diferencia entre & y -> en una estructura?

Tags: c

Si tengo una estructura x con un elemento a en esta estructura, es lo mismo decir (&x)->a que x.a ?
Gracias por su respuesta.

Comment: Probarlo es **muy fácil**, apenas unas líneas.

Comment: Si, pero solo necesito una explicacion de por que es asi... gracias

Comment: Es así porque ambas sintaxis son equivalentes.

Comment: y por que son equivalentes?

Comment: Son equivalentes porque así lo describe el lenguaje en sus bases. Es decir: es así **por diseño**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

La sintaxis `->` es un "azúcar sintáctico" que permite escribir de forma más corta y legible un acceso a una estructura cuando lo que tienes es un puntero a la misma.

Es decir, imagina que `p` es un puntero a una estructura, y que dentro de ella tienes un campo llamado `n`. La sintaxis "normal" para acceder a ese campo sería esta:

```
(*p).n
```

Es decir, primero "desreferencias" el puntero, con lo que tienes una estructura, y luego usas el operador punto para acceder al campo.

Pues bien, esa sintaxis se puede sustituir por esta otra, que es **totalmente equivalente**:

```
p->n
```

Por otro lado, como supongo sabrás, el operador `&` te devuelve la dirección en que se halla una variable, es decir, un *puntero* a esa variable. Así que si tienes una variable de tipo `struct`, digamos `s`, con un campo `n`, `&s` lo que te da es un puntero a la estructura, por lo que se aplica lo antes dicho, las dos sintaxis siguientes serían equivalentes para acceder al campo a través del puntero `&s':

```
(*&s).n
(&s)->n
```

y cualquiera de las dos obviamente es lo mismo que `s.n`

### Adenda

A lo mejor te preguntas por qué los diseñadores del lenguaje introdujeron el operador `->`. A fin de cuentas no parece que la ganancia de legibilidad sea tan grande entre poner `(*p).n`  o poner `p->n` y tampoco es que ayude a teclear menos (solo un carácter).

La sintaxis flecha es *un poco más útil* (aunque podría discutirse aún si merecía la pena incluirla) cuando el campo al que quieres acceder dentro de la estructura, es a su vez otro puntero a otra estructura.

Imagina por ejemplo que tienes una lista enlazada, compuesta por estructuras como esta:

```
struct Nodo {
  int dato;
  struct Nodo* sig;
}
```

donde el campo `sig` es un puntero a otra estructura igual a esta (que por tanto tiene también un puntero a otra igual, etc...)

Imagina que tengo un puntero `p` que apunta a una de estas estructuras. Obtener su dato es sencillo de cualquiera de estas formas:

```
(*p).dato
p->dato
```

Hasta aquí es igual que antes. Pero ahora imagina que quieres acceder al campo dato *del elemento siguiente* en la lista enlazada. Es decir, a través de `(*p).sig` llegas a la siguiente estructura, y quieres el dato de esa segunda. Ahora sí la sintaxis con asteriscos se compica, y la sintaxis flecha es mucho más limpia:

```
(*(*p).sig).dato
p->sig->dato
```

Comment: abulafia, tus respuestas son un tanque de agua en el desierto, hubiese querido tener un profesor que explicase así.